# Difference between assertion and trigger in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, trigger, rdbms

A `trigger` is a *statement* or a *block of statement* which are executed automatically by the system when an event like insert, update or delete takes place on a table.

But I don't know where we use `assertion` and where we use `trigger` in database.
Can anyone explain,

**What is assertion and difference between the assertion and trigger?**

Comment: By assertion, do you mean constraints, like `CHECK` constraints?

Comment: Yes, I mean like constraint.

Comment: Yes, I asked the meaning like asserts

Answer (score 0):

> The difference between triggers and assertions are:

**Triggers** - a trigger is a piece of `SQL` to execute either before or after an update, insert, or delete in a database.

An example of a trigger in plain *English* might be something like: before updating a customer record, save a copy of the current record. Which would look something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggerName
AFTER UPDATE
    INSERT INTO CustomerLog (blah, blah, blah)
    SELECT blah, blah, blah FROM deleted
```

**Assertions** - An assertion is a piece of SQL which makes sure a condition is satisfied or it stops action being taken on a database object. It could mean locking out the whole table or even the whole database.

**Triggers** - Triggers are more powerful because the can check conditions and also modify the data

**Assertions** - Assertions do not modify the data, they only check certain conditions.

**Triggers** - Triggers are linked to specific tables and specific events.

**Assertions** - Assertions are not linked to specific tables in the database and not linked to specific events.

Comment: can you example for asserts

Comment: Can you give example for asserts?

Comment: Refer this link https://classes.soe.ucsc.edu/cmps180/Winter08/trigger.html

Comment: @nidipadias: no relational DBMS today implements assertions - including Postgres

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I know that, but I want to know what is assert? when we use?  and difference between assert and trigger.

Comment: @nidipadias: *when we use?* – well, we never use them, because they are not supported. I realise that kind of answer isn't helpful, but honestly I don't find the question very helpful either since it's about a feature that you can't really use.

Comment: *"Assertions are not linked to specific tables."* I seriously doubt that. Can you give an example?